# Simple directed graph with some dashed edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

My code here does what I would like, except some node outlines are dashed where they should be solid. I realise I am probably putting the dashed in the wrong place, but I just tried my way to this.

```
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, fill=black!50, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8,->,shorten >=2pt]
    \draw (0,0) node {} -- (1,1) node {};
    \draw (1,1) node {} -- (2,1) node {};
    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (3,2) node {};
    \draw (3,2) node {} -- (4,1) node {};

    \draw (0,2) node {} -- (1,1) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (1,2) node {} -- (2,1) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (3,2) node {};
    \draw (3,2) node {} -- (4,1) node {};

    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (3,0) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (2,0) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (3,0) node {} -- (4,0) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (3,0) node {} -- (4,-1) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (1,1) node {} -- (1,0) [dashed] node {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `dashed` is in the right place, it applies to the whole `draw` command. It would probably make more sense semantically if you put it straight after `\draw`, but it doesn't have an effect on the output. The nodes are dashed because they're constructed as part of the dashed `\draw` command. To make the node borders unbroken, you can add `solid` to your `every node` style.

Here's your adapted code. Note that I've used the current syntax `\tikzset{<style>/.style={<options>}}`, which supersedes the `\tikzstyle` syntax.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        solid,
        fill=black!50,
        inner sep=0pt,
        minimum width=4pt
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8,->,shorten >=2pt]
    \draw (0,0) node {} -- (1,1) node {};
    \draw (1,1) node {} -- (2,1) node {};
    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (3,2) node {};
    \draw (3,2) node {} -- (4,1) node {};

    \draw  (0,2) node {} -- (1,1) node {};
    \draw (1,2) node {} -- (2,1) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (3,2) node {};
    \draw (3,2) node {} -- (4,1) node {};

    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (3,0) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (2,0) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (3,0) node {} -- (4,0) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (3,0) node {} -- (4,-1) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (1,1) node {} -- (1,0) [dashed] node {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Jake's answer is correct but the way to draw this graph is not fine. First because we can avoid some code with style applied to some groups and I don't like the fact to (re)draw some nodes. It's possible without name the nodes to get the graph but we need to use `shorten` for `<`and `>`

1) we draw the nodes 2) we draw solid edges 3) we draw dashed edges

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        %solid, no necessary now because the nodes are drawn first
        fill          = black!50,
        inner sep     = 0pt,
        minimum width =4 pt
    }   
}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8,->,
                   shorten >=2pt+0.5*\pgflinewidth,
                   shorten <=2pt+0.5*\pgflinewidth,
                   every node/.style={circle,
                                      draw,
                                      fill          = black!50,
                                      inner sep     = 0pt,
                                      minimum width =4 pt}]
\path[draw] % we place the nodes once
       node at (0,0) {}  
       node at (1,1) {} 
       node at (2,1) {} 
       node at (3,2) {} 
       node at (4,1) {} 
       node at (3,0) {} 
       node at (2,0) {} 
       node at (4,0) {} 
       node at (4,-1){}
       node at (0,2) {} 
       node at (1,0) {} 
       node at (1,1) {} 
       node at (1,2) {} ; 

    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) ; % it's possible because we use shorten at each side
    \draw (1,1) -- (2,1) ;
    \draw (2,1) -- (3,2) ;
    \draw (3,2) -- (4,1) ; 
    \draw (0,2) -- (1,1) ;

\begin{scope}   [dashed]  % now dashed is for the lines inside the scope
     \draw (1,2) -- (2,1)  ; 
     \draw (2,1) -- (3,0)  ;
     \draw (2,1) -- (2,0)  ;
     \draw (3,0) -- (4,0)  ;
     \draw (3,0) -- (4,-1) ;
     \draw (1,1) -- (1,0)  ; 
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]